# crear varios objetos y asignarle acciones

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando las mismas acciones para diferentes elementos y quiero saber si se podría acortar el código y como hacerlo.
Se trata de una pagina con 3 vídeos que quiero que se reproduzcan o dejen de hacerlo al pasar el mouse por arriba o salir.

El código HTML para los vídeos es el siguiente (que repito 3 veces con diferentes id):

```js
controls = [];
player1 = new Plyr('#player1', {
  controls
});
window.player1 = player1;
player2 = new Plyr('#player2', {
  controls
});
window.player2 = player2;
player3 = new Plyr('#player3', {
  controls
});
window.player3 = player3;
$("#demo1btn").hover(function() {
  player1.play();
});
$("#demo1btn").mouseout(function() {
  player1.stop();
});
$("#demo2btn").hover(function() {
  player2.play();
});
$("#demo2btn").mouseout(function() {
  player2.stop();
});
$("#demo3btn").hover(function() {
  player3.play();
});
$("#demo3btn").mouseout(function() {
  player3.stop();
});
```

```html
<div class="btn p-0" id="demo1btn">
  <video class="video-fluid" id="player1" poster="fotos/demo1.jpg" playsinline loop>
        <source src="demo1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

Calculo que si voy por la clase .video-fluid en lugar de los IDs, podría arrancar los 3 juntos con un for... pero no sé bien si habría algún conflicto con el window.player ni como se haría, y lo mismo con los hover y mouseout, se que tengo que ir por la clase btn, pero adentro me perdí con el selector para identificar el elemento con el $(this "#video-fluid") y no me salió.

¿Alguien podría por favor ayudarme con esto?

Comment: Puedes crear una función que reciba los parámetros necesarios para que de esta forma, dicha función te sirva para N elementos.. a simple vista el método que debieses crear necesitaría como parámetro un **idPlayer** y un **idBtn**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé cuánto lo quieres acortar, pero podrías hacer simplemente esto:

```
for( let i = 1; i < 4; i++ ){
    const player = new Plyr('#player' + i, { controls: [] });
    window['player' + i] = player;
    $(`#demo${i}btn`).hover(() => player.play(), () => player.stop());
}
```

Y a partir de ahí, si quisieras manejar algún Plyr, los sigues teniendo en el objeto `window`.

El método `hover()` de jQuery acepta 2 argumentos de tipo function, uno para `mouseenter` y otro para `mouseleave`.

PD: El código es ES6, por lo que puede que quieras convertirlo a ES5 o [compilarlo](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

Comment: Muchas gracias! me termine quedando con tu respuesta que es la que mas acorto el tema y hace algo parecido a lo que tenia en mente, eso de usar un for para iniciar o declararlos y después lo del hover.... una genialidad! no sabia que se podía meter ahí mismo, y no sabia lo de los 2 argumentos! Por eso cuando estaba probando con un alert, en un momento algunas cosas funcionaban pero me tiraba 2 alert en lugar de 1, y es claro porq estaba tomando el enter y el leave! me aclaraste ese interrogante también en la misma respuesta! Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Una sola preguntita más, porque tuve que agregarle el "controls = [];" antes y reemplazar el "[]" por "{ controls }", alguna idea de porque no funciona con [] solo o con {[]} ? El array de controls asi vacio es para esconderle los controles al script de plyr.js (https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.6/plyr.js), y con los corchetes de todas formas muestra los controles (cuando yo quiero ocultarlos), y con las llaves y corchetes me figura como un error de sintaxis, también probé solo con llaves y no hay error de sintaxis pero tampoco funciona...

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirva el código. Realmente sería `{ controls: [] }` para que funcione, no me fijé yo bien a la hora de construir el ejemplo, pensando que el segundo parámetro era un array. Pero mirando la documentación veo que es un objeto en el que una de sus propiedades es "controls" y su valor un array, función o elemento. Edito el código el post para reflejar el cambio 

Answer (score 3):

Para simplificar un poco ese código lo que hice fue crearle un atributo a todos los div btn que tenias donde indico el # del player y especifico que es el que voy a leer para asignarle el evento hover y mouseout, luego capturo esos eventos para todos los div que tengan ese atributo, creo los reproductores y los adiciono al objeto window y en cada caso lo reproduzco o lo pauso. Aquí te dejo el código.

Este sería un ejemplo de tu html:

```
<!-- play-btn es el atributo por el cual voy a obtener todos los divs que 
      van a servir para reproducir o pausar el reproductor,
      y data-player="1" es el que me dice que numero va a ser //-->

<div class="btn p-0" play-btn data-player="1">
  <video class="video-fluid" id="player1" poster="fotos/demo1.jpg" playsinline loop>
    <source src="demo1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div class="btn p-0" play-btn data-player="2">
  <video class="video-fluid" id="player2" poster="fotos/demo2.jpg" playsinline loop>
    <source src="demo2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Ahora tu javascript quedaría más o menos así:

```
controls = [];

$('[play-btn]').each(function(index, item){
    var player_id = $(item).attr('data-player');
    var name = 'player'+player_id;
    window[name] = new Plyr('#'+name, { controls })
})

$('[play-btn]').hover(function(){
    var player_id = $(this).attr('data-player');
    window['player'+player_id].play();
});

$('[play-btn]').mouseout(function(){
    var player_id = $(this).attr('data-player');
    window['player'+player_id].stop();
});
```

Pruébalo y me dices suerte ;P

**EDITADO**
Se me habia kedado el $(item) del each sorry. Si te funciona porfavor marcala como correcta

Comment: Muchas gracias! eh usado atributos antes pero no se había ocurrido usarlos en esta ocasión.... sin dudas una muy buena resolución! Tal cual como esta no funciona, pero si para el hover y mouseout reemplazo "item" por "this", funciona perfecto! Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

crear una clase seria mejor ya que al final si es un juego tendras demaciados player para estar haciendo metodos para todos y no seria acortar si no optimizar:

```js
var controls = controls || {};

class Player{

  //si quieres settearlo desde el constructor
  constructor(player, controls) {
      this.player = player;
      window[player] = this.player;
      this.controls = controls;
    }
    
    // si quieres settear al player manualmente
    setPlayer(player){
      this.player = player;
      window[player] = this.player;
    }

    //recupera al player actual
    getPlayer(){
      return this.player;
    }

    // cada player tendra su accion
    playerAccion(){
      let player = this.player;
      //code  

    }
}



var player = [];

function ExistPlayer(gp){
  for(x of player){
     if(x.getPlayer() == gp) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function updatePlayer(){
  let data ="";
  for(x of player){
    data += `<option>${x.getPlayer()}</option>`;
  }
  $('select[id="select"]').html(data).show();
  $('span[id="np"]').text(player.length);
}

$('form[id="form"]').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let p = $(this).find("#player").val();

  if ($.trim(p) != '') {
        if(!ExistPlayer(p)){
           let play = new Player(p,controls);
           player.push(play);
           updatePlayer();
           console.log("new player add!");
           $(this).find("#player").val("");
        }else{ alert(`player ${p} ya existe!`);} 
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
player:<span id="np"></span>
<select id="select" style="display:none;">
</select>
<br>
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="player" id="player" value="" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*"  required><button>setPlayer</button>
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! esto es algo avanzado para mi creo... lo voy a tener que mirar con mas detenimiento para poder entenderlo, por ahora me quede con otra solución ya que buscaba solo acortar un poquito, no se trata de un juego en este caso y no voy a tener mas que 3 players, pero en cuanto tenga un tiempito lo miro mejor y seguro algo le saco también! Gracias Bryro!